# how to handle data driven for passing value in URL

Tags: dsl, karate

My query is how to handle data driven for passing value in URL. For example
URL 'http:// localhost:8080/
//*Def id ='1'
Given path URL,'cat',id

id 
1

I want to passing the  dynamic value in id
http://localhost:8080/cat/1
http://localhost:8080/cat/2

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please edit it so as to include what you *precisely* mean by `handle data driven for passing value in URL`, if you're talking about server-side or client-side development, and what are the technologies that you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Please take the time to read the documentation, it will really help you: https://github.com/intuit/karate#url

Try this example, you can paste it into a new feature file and see it work:

```
Scenario Outline: data driven url path
  Given url 'https://httpbin.org'
  And path 'anything', <id>
  When method get
  Then status 200
  And match response.url == 'https://httpbin.org/anything/' + <id> 

  Examples:
    | id |
    | 1  |
    | 2  |
```