# Is this possible to use dataGenerator inside Json?

Tags: json, karate

Have a little problem.
I have a feature postUser with request body, which I provide inside this feature.
Body doens't have unique data, it filled manually.
I know that I can read this requestBody from requestBody.json but I dont know how to connect data generator to this json and even if this a possible.
So, my json looks like this

```
{
"first_name": "test",
"last_name": "user",
"email": "test@sjdas.com",
"phone_number": "12341415",
"image": "",
"status": "INACTIVE",
}
```

And I want to have dataGenerator inside this json like this

```
{
"first_name": "#(userName)",
"last_name": "#(userLastName)",
"email": "#(userEmail)",
"phone_number": "#(userPhoneNumber)",
"image": "",
"status": "INACTIVE",
}
```

Is this possible to have the next scenario if yes, how can I do this?

```
* path 'user'
And request requestBody
When method Post
Then response 200
```

P.S. I'm a newbie in Java, so I don't know how to resolve this(

Comment: there's nothing called "dataGenerator" in karate. maybe you mean "data driven" testing. I suggest you read the documentation instead of asking an open ended question like this. and please scan these answers: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+data+driven - after that please edit your question with a specific example you tried and we can take it from there - and if you need one simple example, here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54810584/143475

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution.
We can't use a data generator inside of the JSON. But we can set the randomly generated value into a JSON file before making the POST request.
All of this should be described inside feature and also JavaFaker should be connected.